# Setting disk partitioning for Ubuntu breaks my system

Tags: 14.04, unetbootin

After setting partitioning on my system for the Ubuntu installation, I have my disk cleared and cannot find a boot file when I'm being prompted "Reboot and select proper boot device".

I only can see few directories here when I'm trying to select a new file to boot when adding a new boot option after pressing Ctrl+Alt+Del and F2 to open the Setup utility.

Neither of these directories seem to have files of the required file type. (.efi)

Please advice me on how can I finish my Ubuntu installation.

I'm using UNetbootin to have a USB-free installation.

Please view these screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You've tagged this as relating to the unsupported Ubuntu 14.04 LTS system, are you sure that's what you're using; Ubuntu 14.04 LTS reached EOSS back in 2019-April, and is thus off-topic here.

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard or public support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in *extended* support and supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades
https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

Comment: Start over and follow official documentation. First, [verify the ISO](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu). Then follow the [tutorial to install Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). You need a USB flash drive. You also need to know how to boot a bootable USB with your particular motherboard. All of your screenshots in this question are from your motherboard firmware. This is unrelated to Ubuntu. If you need help with your motherboard, read the manual or use support channels for your motherboard hardware. If you still need help, reference the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Start over and follow [the official documentation](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop).

Follow each step. Do not skip steps. Do not take shortcuts. Do not try to outwit the installer.

- "*I'm using Unetbootin to have a USB-free installation.*" Unetbootin does not have that capability. Unetbootin cannot be used for that purpose. That is the cause of your problem.